# Google Chrome says IcedTea is out of date

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, icedtea

IcedTea for Google Chrome won't work. What happens is this - when I visit the Java test page http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp, Chrome throws this:

[image]

When I click `Update plug-in...`, it just redirects to IcedTea's website!

Is there any way that I can update it so Chrome doesn't show the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and is reported at:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/1024177
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138386

Comment: I'll check on it every week or so for a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Works now. Visited Powder Game and it loaded!